# How to call a local file/online file if you are using repl.it?

Tags: python, discord.py, replit

I would let my discord bot(python) into the voice channel and play an audio, but I'm Using repl.it, how should I do?
Sorry about my English :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply upload it to your working directory

[image]